# Vite serves up jsx files in network traffic

Tags: vite

I'm not sure what is going on but I have a very basic Vite setup, yet I'm seeing the local server serve up all my jsx files, which takes a good 10-15s when I do a fresh reload.
At first I thought this just might be the way Vite works for development but even when trying to build for production it does the same thing and doesn't minimize or uglify the files but just serves the jsx as is.

[image: Browser Network tab screenshot]

The following is my `vite.config.js`.  The commented out code is other things that I've tried with no success:

```js
export default ({mode}) => {
  return defineConfig({
    root: 'app',
    define: {global: 'window'},
    // esbuild: {
    //   loader: "jsx",
    //   minify: true,
    //   minifySyntax: true,
    // },
    // optimizeDeps: {
    //   esbuildOptions: {
    //     minify: true,
    //     minifySyntax: true,
    //     loader: {
    //       ".js": "jsx",
    //       ".ts": "tsx",
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
    plugins: [react()],
    // build: {
    //   outDir: '../dist',
    //   minify: true,
    // },
    server: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 3000
    }
  })
};
```

I've tried numerous configuration options and tried every rollup/vite config option I could find on stack overflow and the internet.  I'd expect vite to serve only the produced index.html and generated index.jsx file, not get all my source files as is.

This project originally did use webpack, but even then I wasn't doing anything special.  Here is my webpack config incase that's helpful:

```js
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    module.exports = {
        mode: 'development',
        devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        entry: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://vesta-dev.localhost.com:3000',
            'webpack/hot/dev-server',
            'react-hot-loader/patch',
            path.join(__dirname, 'app/index.js')
        ],
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
            filename: '[name].[hash].js',
            publicPath: '/'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser',
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                ...
            })
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: [/node_modules/, /__tests__/],
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '.eslintrc'),
                        failOnWarning: false,
                        failOnError: false,
                        emitError: false,
                        emitWarning: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel']
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]---[local]---[hash:base64:5]']
                },
                { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: '10000',
                        mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
                    }
                },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
            ]
        }
    };
```

Comment: This is crazy, I just came to this question searching for the same. Not only this is madness for resource serving but also a security breach since it's exposing crucial info such as API keys

Comment: Hi, you could publish a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will be easier to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is normal for when you use `vite serve` as that always serves the development environment, no matter what flags you set or command line options you pass in.

I thought it was interesting that no one talks about the jsx files actually being served in the network traffic and even with all my searching never came across anyone talking about this, nor in the Vite documents so I thought something was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"preview": "vite build --watch --mode preview & vite preview --mode preview"` [github](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/15698#discussioncomment-8220358)